# TicTacToe project in Python 2: I am trying to avoid using global variables and return variables instead

Tags: python, python-2.7, tic-tac-toe

I am working on a project, and I have no idea how to avoid using global variables. I have a list of functions that perform bits and pieces but I am not able to pass variables between them!

Here is my current code:

===================

```
def player_names_input():
    global player_A_name,player_B_name
    player_A_name = raw_input("Please enter name for Player A    :   ")
    player_B_name = raw_input("Please enter name for Player B    :   ")

def coin_flip():
    global player_A_name,player_B_name,start_player,end_player,game_state
    game_state = "running"
    import random
    print "\nFlipping a coin to see who starts first..."
    random_int = random.randint(0, 1)
    if random_int == 0:
        coin = 'Heads'
        start_player = player_A_name
        end_player = player_B_name
    else:
        coin = 'Tails'
        start_player = player_B_name
        end_player = player_A_name
    print '\nCoin flip --> ',coin
    print '\nStarting player --> ',start_player
    print '\nStarting player gets "X"'

player_names_input()
coin_flip()
```

Here is my failed attempt to use return instead of global:

=========================================================

```
def player_names_input():
    player_A_name = raw_input("Please enter name for Player A    :   ")
    player_B_name = raw_input("Please enter name for Player B    :   ")
    return player_A_name,player_B_name

def coin_flip(player_A_name,player_B_name):
    game_state = "running"
    import random
    print "\nFlipping a coin to see who starts first..."
    random_int = random.randint(0, 1)
    if random_int == 0:
        coin = 'Heads'
        start_player = player_A_name
        end_player = player_B_name
    else:
        coin = 'Tails'
        start_player = player_B_name
        end_player = player_A_name
    print '\nCoin flip --> ',coin
    print '\nStarting player --> ',start_player
    print '\nStarting player gets "X"'

player_names_input()
coin_flip(player_A_name,player_B_name)
```

1- Please help make my second code run, I really wanna avoid global variables as everyone recommends.
2- Please critique my code, I am in the beginning and I am trying to learn writing good code (not just code). How bad is my attempt?

Answer (score 1):

Since you have defined `player_names_input()` to return a 2-tuple (the two values, `player_A_name` and `player_B_name`), you could just assign them like so in the scope you are using that function,

```
player_A_name, player_B_name = player_names_input()
```

Now, when this is called:

```
coin_flip(player_A_name, player_B_name)
```

The two variables will be available for use.

You may want to consider wrapping the actual main program in a main method like

```
def main():
    player_A_name, player_B_name = player_names_input()
    coin_flip(player_A_name, player_B_name)
```

And call that if that file was directly executed - this is done by checking the magic `__name__` variable to equal to the string `'__main__'`, so add this too to the end of your program file.

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```